# Tailwind CSS - mx-auto not centering div element?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am building a project in React with Tailwind CSS and I am trying to center `<div>` element with `<div className="container mx-auto">` but it does not center the element. what wrong with the code.

```html
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <header className="bg-red-600">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex justify-between">
        <nav className="flex">
          <NavLink
            to="/"
            exact
            activeClassName="text-white"
            className="inline-flex items-center py-6 px-3 mr-4 text-red-100 hover:text-green-800 text-4xl font-bold cursive tracking-widest"
          >
            Tailwind CSS
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/post"
            className="inline-flex items-center py-3 px-3 my-6 rounded text-red-200 hover:text-green-800"
            activeClassName="text-red-100 bg-red-700"
          >
            Blog
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/project"
            className="inline-flex items-center py-3 px-3 my-6 rounded text-red-200 hover:text-green-800"
            activeClassName="text-red-100 bg-red-700"
          >
            Projects
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/about"
            className="inline-flex items-center py-3 px-3 my-6 rounded text-red-200 hover:text-green-800"
            activeClassName="text-red-100 bg-red-700"
          >
            About
          </NavLink>
        </nav>
        <div>
            
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

[image]

The `<div>` element is centered when I reduce the size of the screen.

[image]

Comment: It is center, no? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gGjN.png

Comment: @charles It's not centering for me. I don't know why .

Comment: could you share a screenshot? I guess you need to resize your window to be bigger?

Comment: @charles https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUHb9.png

Comment: @charles when I reduce the size of the screen the element is centred but not on full screen. Here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNLJV.png

Answer (score 2):

Your class of `mx-auto` is actually doing its job just fine. The trouble is that the `container` class has a `width` of `100%` and has a set `max-width` at each breakpoint so it appears that its not getting centered but its actually just very wide.

Its visibly working at `768px` because the container width is `640px` showing you 64px on either side but at say `1024px` wide `container` has a `max-width` of `1024px` so there wont be any space on either side.

I'd remove the breakpoints where you dont need the container to grow any higher in the Tailwind config file.